# EC2 Port Listening with Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I host 2 different flask applications with docker on EC2. One of them is running at port 80 and the other at port 5000.

My question is;
Can I get a separate elastic ip for port 80 and a separate elastic ip address for port 5000 on AWS? Because if I don't get separate ip for these, I'm having problems with domain redirecting.

Comment: IP addresses are not associated with port numbers. Even if you had separate IP addresses, you would still need to reference port 5000 (eg `1.2.3.4:5000`). If you want both applications to be available without specifying a port number, you would need to use a reverse proxy to redirect traffic to port 5000.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need multiple ENI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html

Comment: do you have some tutorial for that, because i cannot add second ENI on my ec2 instance

Comment: I created my second ENI but I can't get it to listen on the port. When I searched, I could not find any solution about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create and attach another NIC, you can assgin two IPs to the same interface:

- Assigning a secondary private IPv4 address.
- Configuring the operating system on your instance to recognize secondary private IPv4 addresses.
- Associating an Elastic IP address with the secondary private IPv4 address.

See the following link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html

After the discussion in comments, you should be binding to 0.0.0.0 if you want the container to be accessible from outside. If you have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Change it to, in your both flask app

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Thank your for your comment, i got a two questions;

- I got my second private ipv4 address and I can see it in my ec2 instance. Also, I connected the second ipv4 address with a different elastic ip. But when I enter the elastic ip I linked, it does not redirect me to the page. What could be the reason for this?

-  How can I use ipv4 addresses to listen for ports?

@asri-badlah

Comment: Can you confirm that your two flask application running correctly, for example what is the result of these two commands: curl http://localhost:80" and
curl http://localhost:5000

Comment: Two of them, get results. its running correctly.

Comment: i can access my first ipv4 and elastic ip, but i cannot access with my second ip

Comment: So how do I get to listen to the 5000 and 80 ports of these ip's?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means all ips